# Getting an element by id in Google App Engine's JDO

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo, gql

I have a problem when trying to find a single element
by id. The entity class is this:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class Test{

   @PrimaryKey
   private String name;

//..and so on.
```

In this case, the value "name" is acting like an id. I'm using this
query to find the element:

```
           PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

           Query q = pm.newQuery(Test.class);
           q.setFilter("name == " + id);

           //String query = "SELECT FROM " + Test.class.getName() + "WHERE name == " + id;
           Test test = (Test) q.execute();

           return category;
```

Assuming id is a string value sent as a parameter by other method.

But it doesn't retrieve any data. Also, it throws an exception:
**java.lang.ClassCastException:
org.datanucleus.store.appengine.query.StreamingQueryResult cannot be
cast to com.santiagopoli.gapptest.domain.Test**

The commented query also doesn't work.

I hope anyone can help me. Is a shame that something that basic is
difficult to achieve. In other sql implementations, it will be easy as
typing "select * from Test where id=". Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I just fixed it.

Try this...

```
Test t = pm.getObjectById(Test.class, id);
```

reference...
http://code.google.com/intl/us/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/creatinggettinganddeletingdata.html